# How to make input side by side with limited html structure

Tags: html, css

I have limited html structure on my html form, basically, I can't wrap it with div, so I use inline-block to make the input side by side, however, when error message shows up, it makes my input stacks up, instead of inline.

When I check the error message, it seems there's a width, so I use width 30%, however, my input still not inline.

I tried different display, but no luck, any idea to make my input inline with limited html?

```html
<p class="form-field  phone pd-text required   error ">
                
    <label class="field-label">Téléphone</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="40" onchange="" onfocus="" placeholder="Téléphone">
</p>

<p class="error no-label" style="border: 1px solid;width: 170px;">This field is required</p>
```

[image: width 30% but still shows margin]

Comment: Do you have accompanying CSS or are you using a framework? Also, why can't you use a div?

Comment: I’m working on the crm tool to create form which the field is added automatically from the system, I can’t wrap with div. I don’t use any frameworks, just regular css. The display inline-block works, however when error message shows up, it makes my input stack up instead of inlining

Comment: Are you able to use an HTML 5 form? They have built-in error messages on submit that hover over content as opposed to pushing it around. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/sytw2rqb/2/

Comment: Yes I think it’s built in with html 5 form, I don’t see that hover tho after I click submit on my form page. Also we have a mockup, so not sure if we can change it to hover. If this not possible, I’m thinking to tell the pm if the client is okay to use 100% width instead of inline them, however, I feel there must be a way to fix this even with limited structure

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/sytw2rqb/3/ <- How about that? You just have to add `required` to the input field

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for the help, really appreciate it,I will check with my project manager if he’s okay with the hover error

Comment: I'd hope so. Unless he needs some super-specific design for the error message this is an absolutely painless method of handling form validation thanks to HTML 5

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main {
width:500px;
}

.input-group {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
width:100%;
gap:2rem;
}

label {
 width:50%;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}

label span {
 font-size:0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label>
      <span>Name</span>
      <input id="name" name="name">
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Telefon</span>
      <input id="name" name="name">
    </label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This would work in normal html structure, however, as I mention, my structure can’t be wrapped with div.